# What is the data on /tracks/{id}/shared-to/users for?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am a new member for the SoundCloud JS API, and I have a basic question on it.

I found there is `/tracks/{id}/shared-to/users` in the subresource of tracks. But I do not know what is it for.

I try to get the value via the following code, but I always get the 404 failed. Could anybody give me some suggestion?

```
SC.get("/tracks/153996284/shared-to/users", function(users) {
    console.log(">>get shared users Return");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API reference, it says it returns a list of "users who have access to the track."  I'd say it is a list of people that can access a private track.  One of two things may be going on when you get the 404,

1. The subresource only exists for private tracks.
2. Your account has to have permissions to get that subresource of a particular track.

Try uploading a track and making it private, then play around with it.  Make sure you have authorized with SC.connect, also.

Comment: Ohh~I have done all of above: upload a private track -> auth my app with SC.connect -> SC.get("/tracks/153996284/shared-to/users"). But I still get 404 error

Comment: I also received a 404 while trying to get it.  They may have changed the way they handle private track sharing.  I'm not sure how they used to handle private track sharing, but it looks like you just send a uri with a secret token when you want to share it now. http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1522764